# Best way to adapt Guava's AbstractExecutorService to achieve (gRPC) context propagation?

Tags: java, grpc, guava

I had hoped to find a simple class that just does this in gRPC Context library, but sadly no luck. I want to wrap an arbitrary `ExecutorService` so it will wrap its tasks in order to propagate the current context of the thread which submitted them.

So far I have:

```java
import io.grpc.Context;

public final class GrpcPropagatingExecutorService extends AbstractExecutorService {
  private final ExecutorService delegate;

  public GrpcPropagatingExecutorService(ExecutorService delegate) {
    this.delegate = checkNotNull(delegate);
  }

  @Override
  protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
    // Option 1: I could put code here...
    super.newTaskFor(Context.current().wrap(runnable), value);
  }

  @Override
  protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
    // ... and here.
    super.newTaskFor(Context.current().wrap(callable));
  }

  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    // Option 2: Or I could put code here.
    super.execute(Context.current().wrap(command));    
  }

  // Other methods are trivial...
}
```

My question is:
Which is the best approach, or are they equivalent?

Putting the wrapping code in `newTaskFor()` feels better to me, but leaves a problem (i.e. what if someone uses the service as a plain `Executor` and directly calls `execute()`, which isn't wrapping the given `Runnable`?)

Putting the wrapping code only in `execute()` might be okay, but only if that's always called in the thread which is scheduling the task, and never in some worker thread (that's not at all clear from the docs and in theory I think it could be violated by a service which wraps this one).

Putting the wrapping code in both (belt & braces) is possible, but I'd need a new type so I can detect `Runnables` which have already be wrapped (and I don't think even that's particularly robust tbh).

So do I just have to wrap things in both places and suffer wrapping almost all tasks twice, or am I missing something?

EDIT - An alternative idea I just thought of is:

```java
  private static final class GrpcPropagatingTask<V> extends FutureTask<V> {
    public GrpcPropagatingTask(Callable<V> callable) {
      super(Context.current().wrap(callable));
    }

    public GrpcPropagatingTask(Runnable runnable, V result) {
      super(Context.current().wrap(runnable), result);
    }
  }
```

And returning that from `newTaskFor()` methods. Then in `execute()` I can do:

```java
  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (!(command instanceof GrpcPropagatingTask)) {
      command = Context.current().wrap(command);
    }
    delegate.execute(command);
  }
```

which I think would resolve my fears about `execute()` being called directly.

Comment: Are you looking for [`Context.currentContextExecutor`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html#currentContextExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)) ?

Comment: I don't think so, unless there's a way to associate that executor into an arbitrary executor service I was given. I want something which, given a service, returns a wrapping service. What I'd hoped to have seen is `Context.currentContextExecutorService(ExecutorService delegate)`

Answer (score 0):

So far the best answer I can come up with is the alternate suggestion from the question. It seems to work and I can't see an obvious way why it's wrong:

1. Create subclass of `FutureTask` and have it wrap the callable/runnable in the constructor (important to wrap here and not when invoked).

```java
  private static final class GrpcPropagatingTask<V> extends FutureTask<V> {
    public GrpcPropagatingTask(Callable<V> callable) {
      super(Context.current().wrap(callable));
    }

    public GrpcPropagatingTask(Runnable runnable, V result) {
      super(Context.current().wrap(runnable), result);
    }
  }
```

2. Then create a subclass of `AbstractExecutorService` with a `delegate`, and override the `newTaskFor()` methods:

```java
  private final ExecutorService delegate;

  private GrpcPropagatingExecutorService(ExecutorService delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
    return new GrpcPropagatingTask<>(runnable, value);
  }

  @Override
  protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
    return new GrpcPropagatingTask<>(callable);
  }
```

3. Then implement `execute()` to conditionally wrap `Runnable` instances:

```java
  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (!(command instanceof GrpcPropagatingTask)) {
      command = Context.current().wrap(command);
    }
    delegate.execute(command);
  }
```

4. Implement other methods of `AbstractExecutorService` to trivially call the delegate instance (i.e. methods like `shutdown()` or `awaitTermination()` which never see a task/runnable).

Now it should be true that:

1. Any runnables/callables passed to any `ExecutorService` methods will be wrapped with the calling thread's gRPC context.
2. Even using the service as a plain `Executor` will work.
3. Tasks won't be wrapped more than once.

Comment: When you say "Implement other methods of `AbstractExecutorService` to trivially call the delegate instance," are you saying, for example, to implement `submit(Callable<T> task)` to `return delegate.submit(task)`? If so, I don't think that any wrapping would take place. Alternatively, if you mean to implement it with `return delegate.submit(Context.current().wrap(task))`, then I think you can get by without most of the code here. I've left another answer with the approach that I'm thinking of.

Comment: No, the other methods are the ones that don't use tasks at all. `AbstractExecutorService ` takes care of `submit()` and other methods, and only leaves `execute()` needing some thought.

Comment: Ah, thanks, now I get it. My only concern now would be if a caller managed to wrap a `GrpcPropagatingExecutorService` in a `GrpcPropagatingExecutorService`: Then the inner executor's `execute` method would neglect to wrap the input because it sees that it's already been wrapped by the outer executor—but possibly with a different context. That might or might not be a realistic problem.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer remember anything from when we originally wrote the class, but: We have a similar utility. It implements `ExecutorService` directly (without extending `AbstractExecutorService`), and it implements each method by wrapping and delegating:

```java
@Override
public void execute(Runnable command) {
  delegate.execute(Context.current().wrap(command));    
}

@Override
public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
  return delegate.submit(Context.current().wrap(task));    
}

// etc.
```

Comment: My concern with this is that it implicitly relies on knowing that, internally, delegated executors don't call back to their own public methods (thus wrapping things multiple times). At least `AbstractExecutorService` promises that by overriding `newTaskFor()`, you get all the submit methods taken care of with exactly one wrapping.
I suspect, for example, that `submit()` may end up calling `execute()` for at least some implementations of random executor services.
The "other methods" I was talking about are those which don't deal with tasks/runnables etc. (e.g. isShutdown()).

Comment: I think we're safe because we're overriding methods only in the wrapper executor and calling methods only on the delegate. All the wrapper's methods call `Context.current().wrap(...)`, and none of the delegate's methods do, so we're guaranteed to wrap exactly once.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Somehow I was convincing myself this was a super-class / sub-class thing, where calling back would be an issue.